# Pass php variabe to JavaScript function with other parameter

Tags: javascript, php

I have several groups of checkboxes, each group has unique class name, I would like to select all function for each group. I have a JavaScript function like this:

```
function toggle(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
    for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
```

It works when `<INPUT type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" />` and I hard coded class name in javascript function.

I tried:

```
<INPUT type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this,<?php echo $key ?>)" />
```

And change javascript function to function `toggle(source, classname){...}` and `toggle()` then use `arguments[0]` for `source`, `arguments[1]` for `classname` in original function. Neither of them worked.

What is the right way to add parameter to this function?

Comment: Why are you writing the element with all caps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed some quotes:

```
<INPUT type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this,'<?php echo $key ?>')" />
```

Comment: Glad to help :) Please consider accepting this answer.